Capacitor Splash Screen - Ionic React
I'm trying to implement a splash screen on my Ionic React project using Capacitor Splash Screen Plugin.
In my capacitor.config.ts I have the splash resource name as 'splash', which is default, but when I build the app for android using Android Studio it doesn't use Capacitor´s default splash screen. What else do I have to do?
import { CapacitorConfig } from '@capacitor/cli';

const config: CapacitorConfig = {
  appId: 'com.fofashion.app',
  appName: 'FOSSIL',
  webDir: 'build',
  server: {
    androidScheme: 'https'
  },
  plugins: {
    SplashScreen: {
      androidSplashResourceName: "splash",
      launchShowDuration: 3000,
      launchAutoHide: true,
      launchFadeOutDuration: 3000,
      // backgroundColor: "#e6e6e6",
      androidScaleType: "CENTER_CROP",
      // showSpinner: true,
      // androidSpinnerStyle: "large",
      iosSpinnerStyle: "small",
      // spinnerColor: "#000000",
      splashFullScreen: true,
      splashImmersive: true,
      layoutName: "launch_screen",
      useDialog: true,
    },
  }
};

export default config;

I tried following multiple tutorials but every single one if them were different. Then I simply went and checked Capacitor's documentation on the Plugin and tired doing it myself, with no success.

You have to compile the resources in the resources folder. An easy way to do this is by running the command:
ionic cordova resources [platform] [options]
Please remember to have the icon and splash in resources
